ADO - On exporting the test cases to CSV or Excel, it doesn't display the "Description" field
On ADO, trying to export the test cases in CSV or Excel format, the field listed as "Description" under "Summary" tab is never exported.
This is the Summary tab and Description is populated under the Summary tab
This is the final export, and the field for "Description" doesn't display
I don't have admin rights on the ADO, just normal user rights, so i cannot add/download any external plugins

I am afraid that Azure DevOps doesn't support exporting the Description(Under Summary) to Excel/CSV when using Test Plan -> Test Case -> Export Test Cases to CSV/XLSX option.
The custom column option also doesn't include the Description Column.

I can fully understand your requirement. Here is a suggestion ticket with the same requirement: Bulk exporting test cases from test plan tab containing description
For a workaround, you can query the test cases in Boards -> Queries. Then you can add the Description Column in the Query to get the Description field value.

You can export the test case work items with the Export to CSV option in Queries.
